# Do I have to initialize a char* after malloc?

Tags: c, string, malloc

I have a program that reads chars into a dynamic string buffer. We do not know the size of the string, and it is a requirement that we do not simply set a fixed-size, "large-enough" buffer.

The relevant function works like this:

```
char* read_field(FILE* data)
{
    int size = 8;

    char *field = malloc(size);
    if (field == NULL)
        exit(1);

    char *tmp = NULL;
    int idx = 0;
    int ch = EOF;

    while (ch) {
        ch = fgetc(data);

        // Double size if full
        if (size <= idx) {
            size *= 2;
            tmp = realloc(field, size);
            if (!tmp) 
                exit(1);
            field = tmp;
        }

        field[idx++] = ch;

        // Relevant termination in my use case
        if (ch == ';' || ch == '\n')
            ch = 0;
    }

    printf("field: %s\n"); // value correct, but sometimes valgrind error

    return field; // field is free'd by the caller
}
```

Now the program seems to work, but when running it through Valgrind I get the errors `Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation` and `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`. These error appears arbitrarily (sometimes) when I call functions like `printf` or `strlen`, as seen in the code above.

This problem is sorted if I use `calloc` instead of `malloc` / `realloc`, but then the reallocation process becomes messier.

Is the Valgrind error something that could be ignored if the program works fine? What are the implications of not initializing the memory to zero? If this can't be ignored, what's the best design to sort it out?

Comment: `printf("field: %s\n");` is UB

Comment: You forgot to nul-terminate your string before passing it to `printf`.

Comment: Hi, yes, sorry I had tried that - edited it in. The valgrind error persists though, any ideas?

Comment: `ch = '\0'` rather than `ch = 0;`. If you intend to use `calloc` why would reallocation process become messier?

Comment: Actually sorry - it seems like it was the null termination of the string all along, I had implemented it incorrectly. Case closed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put a string terminator at the end of the string.

PS:
If you want to clear some memory use memset, it's faster than a for cycle

Comment: Yes - sorry about that - I had already tried that and I've edited it in. The valgrind error persists though.

About memset, are you suggesting I do `memset(str, 0, n)` after every malloc and realloc?

Comment: It was the string terminator all along, edited the fix and solved.

Answer (score 1):

use **calloc** , its much better than **malloc** and **memset**.

## Example

```
char *string = calloc( 100 , sizeof(char*));
// Calloc automatically fills the memory blocks
// Its much faster than malloc and memset
// In addition , only in C you don't need typecast for memory allocators
```